# How to store multiple values in One2many field through odoo website

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I have made a **Bulk Inquiry form** in odoo website. In which the fields category, qty, brand are to be repeated on clicking **Click To Select More Products**

Webpage Image:

[image]

The problem which I am facing is, values of first row are stored in database but fails to store the values for the next product/category and I have to store it in One2many field

Here is my code (**controllers.py**):

```
@http.route(['/website_form/'], auth='public', website=True,methods=['POST', 'GET'], csrf=False, type="http")
    def bulkorder(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            contact_name = kwargs.get('contact_name')
            phone = kwargs.get('phone')
            email_from = kwargs.get('email_from')
            partner_name = kwargs.get('partner_name')
            designation = kwargs.get('designation')
            gst_no = kwargs.get('gst_no')
            name = kwargs.get('name')
            description = kwargs.get('description')
            category = kwargs.get('category')
            quantity = kwargs.get('quantity')
            brand = kwargs.get('brand')
            select_type = kwargs.get('select_type')
            lines = [(0,0,{'category':category,
                           'quantity':quantity,
                           'brand':brand})]
            user_data = {
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'phone': phone,
                'email_from': email_from,
                'partner_name': partner_name,
                'designation': designation,
                'gst_no': gst_no,
                'name':name,
                'description': description,
                'select_type': select_type,
                'bulk_order_line':lines,
                'select_type':select_type,
                }
            store = http.request.env['bulk.order']
            store.create(user_data)
            store.bulk_order_line.write({})
            return http.local_redirect('/contactus-thank-you')
```

models.py:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api,_
from odoo.exceptions import UserError
from odoo import SUPERUSER_ID

class EIndustry_bulkorder(models.Model):
    _name = 'bulk.order'


    contact_name=fields.Char(string="Full Name")
    phone=fields.Char(string="Phone Number", limit=10)
    email_from=fields.Char(string="Email") 
    partner_name=fields.Char(string="Company Name")
    designation=fields.Char(string="Designation")
    gst_no=fields.Char(string="GST Number")
    name=fields.Char(string="Subject")
    description=fields.Char(string="Your Question")
    category=fields.Char(string="Product/Category")
    quantity=fields.Char(string="quantity")
    brand=fields.Char(string="Brand/Make")
    lead=fields.Char(string="Lead")
    select_type=fields.Many2one('bulk.retailer' , string="Profession",
                                required=True , store = True) 
    bulk_order_line = fields.One2many('bulk.bulk_order_lines','bulk_order_line_id',
                                      string='Bulk Order Lines')

class retailerType(models.Model):
    _name='bulk.retailer'

    name = fields.Char(string="Retailer Name")


class BulkOrderLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'bulk.bulk_order_lines'

    bulk_order_line_id=fields.Many2one('bulk.order','bulk_order_line',
        ondelete='cascade', index=True, copy=False)
    category=fields.Char(string="Product/Category")
    quantity=fields.Char(string="Quantity")
    brand=fields.Char(string="Brand")
```

Comment: Can you send **kwargs hash

Comment: The problem is you are sending only a single set of bulk_order_line in your create hash. For multiple lines, you'll have to create an array of values. 

You'll have to create lines 
[(0,0,{values1}), (0,0,{values2}), (0,0,{values3})...] for storing multiple values.

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta I tried this but its not working

Comment: Can you post the error